# http requests time out with ruby (net/http and rest-client) but fast with curl + py

Tags: ruby, http, curl, rest-client

I'm calling a java service via its http endpoint (embedded jetty). The service handles async http requests with a timeout of 5s, and reliably works when I call it from the browser with url params, or curl or py script.

When I call it from a ruby script with net/http or rest-client, it times out half the time?! Any idea what could be causing this and what a possible solution might be (with ruby)?

I'm using ruby 1.9.3-p125 and the ruby and python scripts are all <10 lines (I'd normally be making the call from a larger piece of code, but the small version doesn't work either).

net/http

```
paramStr = "rid=#{rid}&id=#{id}&json=#{json}"
uri = URI.parse(URI.escape(proxy_server_addr+"?"+paramStr))
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
```

rest-client

```
resource = RestClient::Resource.new('http://myserver.com:9001', :timeout => 10)
response = resource["/"].get :params => {:id => id, :rid => rid, :json => json}
```

curl

```
curl 'http://myserver:9001/?id=...'
```

py

```
import urllib2
print urllib2.urlopen("http://myserver.com:9001?id=...").read()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it. The ruby equivalent of urllib2 is open-uri:

```
require 'open-uri'
puts open("http://myserver.com:9001?id=...").read
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Any idea why the other libraries would time out?

Comment: Yes, from what I can tell, you were using them completely wrong :)

Comment: ah! I managed to get rest client to work too... but neither open-uri or rest-client work consistently remotely. It's bizarre. Here's my follow up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693959/http-calls-behave-differnent-locally-vs-aws-is-it-ruby-or-aws