# HTTP calls behave different locally vs AWS - is it ruby or AWS?

Tags: ruby, http, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, sinatra

I have a weird problem with an API I'm writing. The API has makes http get requests to other services and times out in certain situations- another service being off/unreachable in most cases.

I'm trying to run the system entirely on AWS, but when running the API on there I get frequent timeouts trying to access services on the same instance. The API is written in ruby+sinatra; I never had problems with its python predecessor. If I curl the url for other services from the AWS instance command line, I never get timeouts. When I run the API locally (other services on AWS), it works fine, every single time.

Initially I thought it might be the http library I was using- net/http, which turned out to be problematic even locally. Switching to open-uri or rest-client fixed all local problems, but when I run on AWS I still get timeouts 20% of the time.

The API is ruby+sinatra using open-uri to do http requests. The other services are either ruby+sinatra or java. I'm running on a 32-bit Amazon Linux small instance, ruby 1.9.3, java 1.6; my local machine is Mac with Snow Leopard with ruby 1.9.3 and java 1.6 as well.

Any ideas or tips to further narrow down what might be happening?

---

**UPDATE: My big sinatra app and little sinatra app behave differently!?**

The test version of my sinatra app to call my java service, both running on AWS... works fine.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'uri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'sinatra'

set :port, 6969

get '/wtf' do
  xid = params[:xid]
  state = params[:state]
  service_addr = 'http://prod.myserver.com'
  rid = 'xxx'
  json = "{\"state\":\"#{state}\",\"sid\":\"0xac99d8929a89e6c01b56378336dec3a8L\",\"m\":\"set\",\"rid\":\"#{rid}\",\"id\":\"#{xid}\"}"

  paramStr = URI.escape("rid=#{rid}&id=#{xid}&json=#{json}")
  response = open(service_addr+"?"+paramStr)
  status = response.status[0]
  body = response.read

  body
end
```

The big version, running with Rack + as a better structured sinatra app... fails 20+% of the time!

```
require 'uri'
require 'open-uri'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base

  get '/wtf' do
    xid = params[:xid]
    state = params[:state]
    service_addr = 'http://prod.myserver.com'
    rid = 'xxx'
    json = "{\"state\":\"#{state}\",\"sid\":\"0xac99d8929a89e6c01b56378336dec3a8L\",\"m\":\"set\",\"rid\":\"#{rid}\",\"id\":\"#{xid}\"}"

    paramStr = URI.escape("rid=#{rid}&id=#{xid}&json=#{json}")
    response = open(service_addr+"?"+paramStr)
    status = response.status[0]
    body = response.read

    body
  end

end
```

---

**UPDATE 2: Detailed error readout using mechanize- always a gateway timeout**

For the simple version, it works every time (no timeouts). For the complicated version, here are readouts with mechanize when it works, and doesn't.

When it works:

```
I, [2012-05-22T22:45:53.267464 #11610]  INFO -- : Net::HTTP::Get: /? ### big long get str
D, [2012-05-22T22:45:53.267587 #11610] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept => */*
D, [2012-05-22T22:45:53.267630 #11610] DEBUG -- : request-header: user-agent => Mechanize/2.5.1 Ruby/1.9.3p125 (http://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize/)
D, [2012-05-22T22:45:53.267676 #11610] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-encoding => gzip,deflate,identity
D, [2012-05-22T22:45:53.267713 #11610] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-charset => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
D, [2012-05-22T22:45:53.267750 #11610] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-language => en-us,en;q=0.5
D, [2012-05-22T22:45:53.267787 #11610] DEBUG -- : request-header: host => prod.pixieplug.com:9001
I, [2012-05-22T22:45:53.341814 #11610]  INFO -- : status: Net::HTTPOK 1.1 200 OK
D, [2012-05-22T22:45:53.341916 #11610] DEBUG -- : response-header: content-type => application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
D, [2012-05-22T22:45:53.341962 #11610] DEBUG -- : response-header: transfer-encoding => chunked
D, [2012-05-22T22:45:53.342009 #11610] DEBUG -- : response-header: server => Jetty(8.0.y.z-SNAPSHOT)
D, [2012-05-22T22:45:53.342137 #11610] DEBUG -- : Read 167 bytes (167 total)
98.247.240.63 - - [22/May/2012 22:45:53] "GET /wtf?xid=00:00:00:00:00:17&state=255 HTTP/1.1" 200 167 0.0777
```

When it doesn't:

```
I, [2012-05-22T22:46:23.665908 #11610]  INFO -- : Net::HTTP::Get: /?# long list of params
D, [2012-05-22T22:46:23.666014 #11610] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept => */*
D, [2012-05-22T22:46:23.666053 #11610] DEBUG -- : request-header: user-agent => Mechanize/2.5.1 Ruby/1.9.3p125 (http://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize/)
D, [2012-05-22T22:46:23.666090 #11610] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-encoding => gzip,deflate,identity
D, [2012-05-22T22:46:23.666125 #11610] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-charset => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
D, [2012-05-22T22:46:23.666161 #11610] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-language => en-us,en;q=0.5
D, [2012-05-22T22:46:23.666233 #11610] DEBUG -- : request-header: host => prod.pixieplug.com:9001
I, [2012-05-22T22:46:28.675045 #11610]  INFO -- : status: Net::HTTPGatewayTimeOut 1.1 504 Gateway Timeout
D, [2012-05-22T22:46:28.675156 #11610] DEBUG -- : response-header: content-type => application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
D, [2012-05-22T22:46:28.675195 #11610] DEBUG -- : response-header: transfer-encoding => chunked
D, [2012-05-22T22:46:28.675232 #11610] DEBUG -- : response-header: server => Jetty(8.0.y.z-SNAPSHOT)
D, [2012-05-22T22:46:28.675332 #11610] DEBUG -- : Read 48 bytes (48 total)
Mechanize::ResponseCodeError - 504 => Net::HTTPGatewayTimeOut for http://prod.pixieplug.com:9001/?# long list of params  -- unhandled response:
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mechanize-2.5.1/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:304:in `fetch'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mechanize-2.5.1/lib/mechanize.rb:407:in `get'
    /home/ec2-user/elphi-api/routes/sandbox.rb:15:in `block in <class:MyApp>'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1212:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1212:in `block in compile!'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:785:in `[]'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:785:in `block (3 levels) in route!'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:801:in `route_eval'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:785:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:822:in `block in process_route'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:820:in `catch'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:820:in `process_route'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:784:in `block in route!'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:783:in `each'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:783:in `route!'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:886:in `dispatch!'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:719:in `block in call!'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:871:in `block in invoke'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:871:in `catch'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:871:in `invoke'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:719:in `call!'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:705:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:22:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:47:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:47:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:17:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:47:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:22:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/logger.rb:15:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/showexceptions.rb:21:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lint.rb:48:in `_call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lint.rb:36:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/showexceptions.rb:24:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:20:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/chunked.rb:43:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:137:in `start'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rackup:19:in `load'
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rackup:19:in `<main>'
98.247.240.63 - - [22/May/2012 22:46:28] "GET /wtf?xid=00:00:00:00:00:17&state=255 HTTP/1.1" 500 157221 5.1385
```

Comment: So basically you have 2 sinatra apps trying to communicate with each other locally. My advice is to try to get the problem code as small as possible and post it here.

Comment: The sinatra->java seems to be the problem. when both are on AWS. Sinatra app running on my laptop -> java app on AWS works fine. I will attempt to simplify my code and post it.

Comment: it looks like you might need a slash after service_addr. Also try CGI.escape instead of URI.escape.

Comment: tried former, latter and both, didn't fix the timeout issue. It's interesting that the full sinatra app works fine on my mac but has trouble on the ami.

Comment: How are you running it? With rackup?

Comment: Do you compare 'big long get strs'? Are they identical?

Comment: You can try adding: AGENT.open_timeout, AGENT.read_timeout = 60,60

Comment: Big long str are identical. Adding the agent timeouts doesn't make a difference because the java service times out.

Comment: The current theory is that AWS small instance has too much resource contention going on with 3 separate process I run (2 sinatra apps and one big multithreaded java app). Running on a medium or large instance resolves timeouts, though I have not performed a full on load test to verify this.

Comment: I guess that makes sense but I've run heavy apps on micro instances and never seen that. I never send json data in a query string like that though.

Answer (score 0):

It's a strange looking request, usually json data goes in a post body not the query string. Let's try using mechanize because it gives lots of debug information when you use a logger and maybe that will help you see where the problem is. Slightly refactored code:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'mechanize'
require 'logger'
require 'json'

class Myapp < Sinatra::Base

  AGENT = Mechanize.new
  AGENT.log = Logger.new $stdout

  get '/wtf' do
    rid, sid, xid, state = 'xxx', '0xac99d8929a89e6c01b56378336dec3a8L', params[:xid], params[:state]
    service_addr = 'http://prod.myserver.com/'
    json = {'state' => state, 'sid' => sid, 'm' => 'set', 'rid' => rid, 'id' => xid}.to_json
    response = AGENT.get service_addr, {:rid => rid, :id => xid, :json => json}
    response.body
  end

end
```